# Working Days Javascript with Extra Dates

Tags: javascript, date

I have a function which calculates a date that is passed and adds a given number of days to the result ensuring the outputted date doesn't fall on a weekend.

The function

```
function addWorkingDays(datStartDate, lngNumberOfWorkingDays, blnIncSat, blnIncSun) {
    var intWorkingDays = 5;
    var intNonWorkingDays = 2;
    var intStartDay = datStartDate.getDay(); // 0=Sunday ... 6=Saturday
    var intOffset;
    var intModifier = 0;

    if (blnIncSat) { intWorkingDays++; intNonWorkingDays--; }
    if (blnIncSun) { intWorkingDays++; intNonWorkingDays--; }
    var newDate = new Date(datStartDate)
    if (lngNumberOfWorkingDays >= 0) {
        // Moving Forward
        if (!blnIncSat && blnIncSun) {
            intOffset = intStartDay;
        } else {
            intOffset = intStartDay - 1;
        }
        // Special start Saturday rule for 5 day week
        if (intStartDay == 6 && !blnIncSat && !blnIncSun) {
            intOffset -= 6;
            intModifier = 1;
        }
    } else {
        // Moving Backward
        if (blnIncSat && !blnIncSun) {
            intOffset = intStartDay - 6;
        } else {
            intOffset = intStartDay - 5;
        }
        // Special start Sunday rule for 5 day week
        if (intStartDay === 0 && !blnIncSat && !blnIncSun) {
            intOffset++;
            intModifier = 1;
        }
    }
    // ~~ is used to achieve integer division for both positive and negative numbers
    newDate.setDate(datStartDate.getDate() + new Number((~~((lngNumberOfWorkingDays + intOffset) / intWorkingDays) * intNonWorkingDays) + lngNumberOfWorkingDays + intModifier));
    return newDate;
}
```

I need to now add some dates to this function for it to take into account, these are public holiday's in Sydney Australia. What I am looking to achieve is the following.

`var newDate = addWorkingDays('30/09/2015', 3, false, false);`

In this example the returned date would fall on the `03/10/2015` which is a public holiday and therefore we would need to return the `04/10/2015`

The dates in question are:

```
01/01/2015 New Year's Day
26/01/2015 Australia Day
09/03/2015 Labour Day / Eight Hours Day / Adelaide Cup / Canberra Day
03/04/2015 Good Friday
06/04/2015 Easter Monday
25/04/2015 ANZAC Day
08/06/2015 Queen's Birthday
03/08/2015 Bank Holiday / Picnic Day
05/10/2015 Labour Day
03/11/2015 Melbourne Cup
25/12/2015 Christmas Day
26/12/2015 Boxing Day
```

Given the function above can someone help me to amend the function to take these dates into account.

Comment: Boxing day is the same day as Christmas?!?

Comment: I would maybe put all your forbidden days into a dictionary keyed off the date. Then, when you've calculated a new date check to see if it's in your dictionary. If it is, add 1 day and pass it through your function again (recursively) because if Christmas falls on a Friday, adding one more day isn't going to cut it.

Comment: @MattBurland good spot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is your code gives me errors when I try to call it like you specify, but regardless you should simply be able to check if the date you're going to give as an answer is one of your invalid dates, and if so then return the next working day:

(pseudocode)

```
newDate.setDate(datStartDate.getDate() + new Number((~~((lngNumberOfWorkingDays + intOffset) / intWorkingDays) * intNonWorkingDays) + lngNumberOfWorkingDays + intModifier));
if (newDate == "01/01/2015" || newDate == "26/01/2015" || ....) {
    return addWorkingDays(newDate, 1, blnIncSat, blnIncSun);
}
else {
    return newDate;
}
```

Comment: The date parsed is expected to be a date object, thanks for your answer I will give it a go

Comment: I used this

```if (newDate == newYears || newDate == ausDay || newDate == labourDay || newDate == goodFriday || newDate == easterMonday || newDate == anzacDay || newDate == queensBday || newDate == picnicDay || newDate == labourDay2 || newDate == melbourneCup || newDate == xmasDay || newDate == boxingDay ) {
        return addWorkingDays(newDate, 1, blnIncSat, blnIncSun);
    }
    else {
        return newDate;
    }```